# how to extrapolate quaternions?

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternions

Suppose I have an object whose orientation are given by quaternion q1, q2, q3, ...qn at time isntances 1,2,3,...n on server side.
I want to predict the orientation of object on client side, so that I can keep the virtual world consistent on both sides.

- I send q1 and q2 from server to client.
- on server side I calculate dq = q1' * q2;
- Then on server side I predict q3Predicted by doing q2 * dq;
- Then on server side I check the error between q3 orignal and q3Predicted, if its large I send a new dq which is d1 = q2'*q3.

My two questions are:

1. how should I calculate the dq  is it - q1'*q2 or is it   q2*q1'?
2. how should I check if the predicted has more than 10% error when compare to the orignal quaternion?

Answer (score 0):

> on server side. I want to predict them on client side.

<s>What exactly are you trying to do?</s>

To me it sounds like you're trying to implement an animation system on the GPU and try to keep track of it on the CPU. Whenever you need to keep track of or re-do some calculations you got some flaw in your design. If you do the calculations on the CPU anyway, why spend precious cycles with the same calculation on the GPU?

Just calculate it on the CPU and put it into a uniform. Performance will be better as well, as GPUs are designed to process massive amounts of data in parallel. Just interpolating a handfull of scalars causes too much overhead.

If we're talking about a networked game with a game server, you should have a look into so called *"Kalman filters"*.

Comment: please check the first 3 lines of question , I ve edited them